# Baked Image Artifacts

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

As seen below, when I bake i get these weird artifacts (left side of image).

I have tried:

- Rebaking
- Re unwrap then rebaking
- Merging duplicate meshes/vertices

[image: bake]

Comment: Hello, could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: @moonboots https://easyupload.io/3nfomo

Comment: I meant could you please share the .blend file? Before saving, do a File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend

Comment: @moonboots https://easyupload.io/u37147, sorry im a noob!

Comment: it works fine for me, except I put the Extrusion value at 0.1 and Maximum Ray Distance at 0

Comment: @moonboots, that did the trick thanks, If you want to add an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the *Extrusion* value at 0.1 and *Maximum Ray Distance* at 0.